# Finding the longest (or all) intersection(s) in word level of two strings in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, nsstring, swift3

Assume two strings:

- `String 1`: "Once upon a time there was a beautiful princess named Snow white..."
- `String 2`: "Of course it was a time for a beautiful princess to become one..."

What is the best way to find the longest "intersection" (or all possible intersections) in word level of two strings in Swift? In the previous case it would be: **"a beautiful princess"**.

Comment: Intersection for `word` level or `character` level?

Comment: Intersect for `word level`, I'll add this to the question.

Comment: 1) Split the strings into two arrays of words. 2) Implement an algorithm for the [Longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) and apply it to the two arrays.

Comment: Or the other way round: Use a longest match lib like https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/ and look in the result, what are the word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lib that calculates the diff of two texts. I use [DiffMatchPatch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/), what works for me.

To make it work on word level, you can do two things:

- Get the result and look, whether the the boundaries of a runner is inside a word. In such a case shorten the runner to the word boundaries.
- Translate every distinct word into a single UTF-16 char (what `NSString` uses internally) and than run the diff over that text. Since every word became a letter, the result semantically will contain words instead of letters.